# Assign Group rights to folder

Tags: permissions, directory, users, vsftpd

Hello I am new with ubuntu and I have a question.

I created a user `ABC`. I created a group `XYZ`. I added user `ABC` to group `XYZ` .

I have a folder mounted `mydrive`. I mounted it under as I have attached drive to server  /mnt/mydrive.

I want `XYZ` group-users to have `read and write` rights, as I am going to use the `mydrive` for FTP and in future. If I have a new user, I will add the user in group `XYZ` for the same rights. *Please note: I do not want the user to delete the uploaded files.*

In short, I want to give group `XYZ` rights to folder `mydrive`; read and write rights only.

Many Kind Regards,
Osman

Comment: Well. That's a very generic question. Do you know the `chmod` command?

Comment: I know chmod however need a little assistance please
I just want that Group only have access to that drive .

Comment: It sounds like you want to grant the group **read and write** permissions on the drive, but want to prevent them from **deleting** files, correct? If yes, your answer is here on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/869536).

Answer (score 0):

`chown root:XYZ /mnt/mydrive`

`chmod 1660 /mnt/mydrive`